# Keycloak restrict manage-users role for client to only allow create-user privileges

Tags: keycloak, rbac, keycloak-rest-api

### Objective

I'm would like to create a Keycloak role similar to manage-users which has only the ability to create users in a specific realm.

### Current Progress

I've setup my realm `testRealm`

I've setup my client `testClientA` inside `testRealm`
with Service Account Enabled
and grant_type = `client_credentials`

I've added the `manage-users` role to Service Account Roles to enable the request from my client application to create a new user. **(Working fine)**

### Problem

The problem i'm faced with is the `manage-users` role is far too broad and if the `testClientA` service account is ever compromised, the (attacker / bad actor) has full access to the users in the realm along with group administration.

### Additional Background

Keycloak version = 15.0.2 
Running in PreviewMode with admin_fine_grained_authz enabled

### Note:

I've been looking into *fine-grain admin permissions* to see whether something here might fit my use-case but haven't managed to get anything working successfully. I'm fairly new to Keycloak so would be grateful for as much guidance as possible and welcome alternative approaches to solving this problem.

Comment: This is exactly the same issue i have with my app:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73239414/keycloak-users-security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73239414/keycloak-users-security)